# Loading new assembly when Serializing

Tags: c#, memory-management, assemblies, xml-serialization

I have a loop in a BackgroundWorker that saves some stuff via xml Serialization when needed but this seems to load a new assembly each time

> 'xxyyzz.Main.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded '9skkbvdl'
>
> 'xxyyzz.Main.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'd2k4bdda'

and so on.  Why is this happening? Is there any thing i can do about it? Is this something I should be concerned about? This program will stay running for a long long time with no restart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assemblies are generated on the fly when you create the XML Serializer - I wouldn't be too concerned about it, but if you are, you could hold a reference to the serialiser for your type, and use that in sucessive calls

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing additional arguments into your XmlSerializer? i.e. using a non-default constructor? yup, it does this (as it builds a new serialization assembly each time)... consider creating the serializer in a type initializer and caching it:

```
static readonly XmlSerializer foo;
static MyType() {
    foo = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TypeToSerialize), additionalArgs);
}
```

then use the cached `foo` serializer instance repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The "[***.vshost.exe**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx)" files is part of visual studio debugger.